# Deletion & Closure: How do you tactfully answer when someone asks if you're shopping around, when you are?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I've since edited https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/6672/2423 since its closure, in incorporating the suggestions in the comments. Anything else to clarify?

In the body, I explain how each of all the possible answers aren't tactful.

Answer (score 3):

Since it isn't improved to the point where it can be reopened, there's no sense in undeleting it.

See the comments you got to your original question and the duplicate one.

Feel free to ask for our time and attention again once you've seriously done something with the effort we already provided.

Comment: How hasn't it been "improved to the point where it can be reopened"? I did read all the comments.